# Check if conversation exists

Tags: php, mysql, messaging

I have two tables one for the conversations and one for the messages.

For conversations

```
TABLE `conversations` (
  `ai` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `conv_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_a` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_b` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ai`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

For messages

```
TABLE `conv_msgs` (
  `ai` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `conv_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `from_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `the_msg` longtext NOT NULL,
  `sent_date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sent_time` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `read` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ai`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

So what I am currently looking to do and for some reason I can't figure this out is I need a query that when a user goes to create a conversation it checks to see if the conversation between user_a and user_b already exists. The current users could be either a or b. I guess thats where I am stumped. Any insight?

Comment: So you mean check if a conversation exists `WHERE (user_a = personA AND user_b = personB) OR (user_a = personB AND user_b = personA)`? Something like that ?

Comment: Would it be as simple as that?

Comment: That it is... it worked... maybe I need sleep. hahaha